# how to display dropdown API data in flutter with ID

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown, fetch-api

I want to display API data in a dropdown and I have created the code as below, but when I click on the dropdown, the dropdown cannot be clicked and does not display any data, is there something wrong with the code that I made.I have tried with several references and still this problem has not been resolved
Thank you in advance.

> this model

```
ModelProvince modelProvinceFromJson(String str) =>
    ModelProvince.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String modelProvinceToJson(ModelProvince data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ModelProvince {
  String status;
  String code;
  List<Datum> data;

  ModelProvince({
    required this.status,
    required this.code,
    required this.data,
  });

  factory ModelProvince.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ModelProvince(
        status: json["status"],
        code: json["code"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "code": code,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Datum {
  String id;
  String idWil;
  String nmWil;
  String idIndukWilayah;
  String idLevelWil;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;

  Datum({
    required this.id,
    required this.idWil,
    required this.nmWil,
    required this.idIndukWilayah,
    required this.idLevelWil,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        id: json["id"],
        idWil: json["id_wil"],
        nmWil: json["nm_wil"],
        idIndukWilayah: json["id_induk_wilayah"],
        idLevelWil: json["id_level_wil"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "id_wil": idWil,
        "nm_wil": nmWil,
        "id_induk_wilayah": idIndukWilayah,
        "id_level_wil": idLevelWil,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
      };
}
```

> in widget

```
DropdownSearch<Datum>(
          popupProps: PopupProps.modalBottomSheet(
            // showSearchBox: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, item, isSelected) => ListTile(
              title: Text(item.nmWil),
            ),
          ),
          dropdownDecoratorProps: const DropDownDecoratorProps(
            dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Pilih Provinsi',
            ),
          ),

          dropdownBuilder: (context, selectedItem) =>
              Text(selectedItem?.nmWil ?? 'Belum memilih provinsi'),
          // ignore: avoid_print
          onChanged: (value) => idProv = value?.idIndukWilayah,

          asyncItems: (text) async {
            print("Check Response");
            print(idProv);
            var response = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(
                '$baseUrl/v1/auth/mhs_siakad/biodata/get_wilayah?id=$idProv',
              ),
            );
            if (response.statusCode != 200) {
              return [];
            }
            List allProvinsi =
                (json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>)['data'];
            List<Datum> allModelProvinsi = [];
            allProvinsi.forEach(
              (element) {
                allModelProvinsi.add(
                  Datum(
                    id: element['id'],
                    idWil: element['id_wil'],
                    nmWil: element['nm_wil'],
                    idIndukWilayah: element['id_induk_wilayah'],
                    idLevelWil: element['id_level_wil'],
                    createdAt: element['created_at'],
                    updatedAt: element['updated_at'],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
            return allModelProvinsi;
          },
        ),
```

The response is 200 and okay it worked, but the result is an empty list because I used id

```
$baseUrl/v1/auth/mhs_siakad/biodata/get_wilayah?id=$idProv //data not show
```

but when I create a url like this, I fill in the ID according to the postman, the data appears

```
$baseUrl/v1/auth/mhs_siakad/biodata/get_wilayah?id=000001 //data show
```

in postman
[image]

Comment: The code looks correct, can you verify that the endpoint actually returns that list by printing it in the console after conversion?

Comment: i really recommend you to use `try catch` in your api request. So you know what is the issue.

Comment: error handling is important in flutter. especially when you call the API